# Where do we get the Control Plane IP Range for Private GKE cluster in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to create a private GKE cluster.

I have a subnet with two secondary IP ranges (one for the pods and one for the services).

However, a private GKE cluster also requires an IP address range for the control plane.

I have seen the documents for creating private GKE cluster and I see in their examples they ask you to use `172.16.0.32/28` for the control plane/master IP range.

What I want to understand is that, if the control plane IP range is managed by GCP for a zonal cluster? (if yes how to find it?)

Or,

Do I need to create a separate VPC network altogether for the control plane?

Comment: You can allocate the IP range that the control plan of your `GKE` cluster will have (during the creation process) but according to the documentation: `The control plane runs on a VM that is in a VPC network in a Google-owned project`. Also, no, you don't need to create a `VPC` for your control plane, it will be created for you and the `VPC network peering` will be created for you to connect to the control plane ip range. You can check it in the `VPC network` details. Have you seen [GKE private cluster concepts](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/private-cluster-concept)?

Comment: @DawidKruk so that means I can enter an IP range (let's say /28) for control plane and will just make sure that it does not overlap with the subnet that I'm using for the cluster nodes, pods and services?

Comment: yes you are correct. The `control plane`/`pods`/`services` ip ranges shouldn't overlap each other. Also the `vpc network subnet` shouldn't overlap previously mentioned ip ranges.

Comment: @DawidKruk can you put your comments as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Addressing the first question:

> What I want to understand is that, if the control plane IP range is managed by GCP for a zonal cluster? (if yes how to find it?)

You can allocate the IP range that the control plane of your GKE cluster will have (during the creation process).

According to the documentation:

> #### The control plane in private clusters
>
> Every GKE cluster has a Kubernetes API server that is managed by the [control plane (master)](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-architecture#control_plane). **The control plane runs on a VM that is in a VPC network in a Google-owned project.** A regional cluster has multiple control planes, each of which runs on its own VM.
>
> -- *[Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: ... : Control plane in private clusters](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/private-cluster-concept#the_control_plane_in_private_clusters)*

---

Addressing the second question:

> Do I need to create a separate VPC network altogether for the control plane?

No, you don't need to create a `VPC` for your control plane. It will be created for you. The connection between your network and the control plane will be peered using [VPC Network Peering](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering).

You can check the details by following a path:

`Cloud Console` (Web UI) -> `VPC Network` -> `VPC Networks` -> `VPC_NAME` -> `VPC Network Peering`

---

> @DawidKruk so that means I can enter an IP range (let's say /28) for control plane and will just make sure that it does not overlap with the subnet that I'm using for the cluster nodes, pods and services?

Yes. You are correct. Following ip ranges **shouldn't overlap**:

- `Pods`
- `Services`
- `Control plane`
- `VPC Network`

---

Additional resources:

- *[Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: Private cluster concept](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/private-cluster-concept)*